# Modelling a non-linear resistor on ADS

Tags: resistors, spice, microwave, non-linear, ads

How can I model a non-linear resistor whose current changes according to the equation shown below on Advanced Design System (ADS) or AWR Microwave Office?
$$i(t)=v-v^2-v^3$$
Where v is voltage difference between terminals of the resistor.
How can I create such a resistor?

Comment: In ADS look up "Symbolically Defined Device (SDD)" in the help files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aldrich—I am not really familiar with *Advanced Design System* or *AWR Microwave Office*, but your post is tagged with "spice", so that implies one or both of the packages supports [SPICE netlists](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Spice_Netlist)? And supports [behavioral current sources](http://ltwiki.org/?title=B_sources_%28complete_reference%29)? If so, you could try coding the non-linear resistor's behavior like this:

```
.subckt Rmicrowave pin1 pin2
  Br pin1 pin2 I = V(pin1,pin2) - V(pin1,pin2)**2 - V(pin1,pin2)**3
.ends Rmicrowave
```

[image]